# Rewrite rule to replace every %20 in the URL with an underscore

Tags: seo, htaccess

I would like my current URLs:

```
http://example.com/files/528/Rabba%20Ho%20-%20Falak%20Shabir%20Song.html
```

To look cleaner like this:

```
http://example.com/files/528/Rabba_Ho_-_Falak_Shabir_Song.html
```

This is my current *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?pid=$1&ht=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?pid=$1&page=$2&ht=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?sort=$1&pid=$2&page=$3&ht=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^filedownload/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /fileshow.php?pid=$1&id=$2&ht=$3 [L]
```

How do I modify it to rewrite the encoded spaces and underscores?

Comment: This isn't really something you should do (just) in .htaccess. You need to change these URLs in your application. Otherwise, every time a user clicks on one of your internal links (where they will still see the URL that contains `%20` ie. _spaces_) they will be externally redirected, resulting in two requests to your server, which is not desirable.

Comment: but through .htacess it can posiible to repalce %20 to undersocre

Comment: You first need to change the URLs in your application. A lot of people ask a similar question and they get a plain old .htaccess solution. But it's not correct, unless you change the URLs in your application first. The user can still see and copy the `%20` from your page.

Comment: i have not proper knowldge in PHP . you can fix it

Comment: Then What Is The Way for Clean url

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar question on StackOverflow: [mod_rewrite: replace underscores with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes)

I've modified the answer to replace spaces (decoded %20) with underscore.   It works by recursively applying a rewrite rule as long as there are two or more matches, and then once there is only one, a separate rewrite rule does the redirect.

```
RewriteEngine     On
RewriteRule       ^(/?files/.*/[^/]*?)\s([^/]*?\s[^/]*)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule       ^(/?files/.*/[^/]*?)\s([^/\s]*)$       /$1_$2 [R=301]
```

As others have commented, you will need to make sure your application expects underscores in the URL path, and is generating URLs that have the underscore.

Comment: I like the idea of the recursive rewrite +1. Slight tweak though... the `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the %-decoded URL, so `%20` should be a literal (escaped) _space_ (eg. `\ ` or `\s`) in the pattern. Also, the external redirect (2nd rule) needs a slash prefix on the substitution ie. `/$1_$2` (or include a `RewriteBase /` directive), otherwise you get a "broken" redirect in .htaccess.

Comment: bro you can Edit all Urls like this

Comment: When I OPen this rewrite egine url this 404 error i got

Comment: @Marvel: Yes, you will get a 404, because you also need to change the URLs in your application - as already stated.

Comment: but how to i change

Answer (score 1):

First sorry about my bad english.
I use this in my PHP apps links:

```
<?php $theURL = "http://example.com/files/528/Rabba Ho - Falak Shabir Song.html"; ?>

<a href="<?= str_replace( " ", "_", $theURL ); ?>" target="_blank">
    Rabba Ho - Falak Shabir Song
</a>
```

EDIT: Sorry for last error, i edit now...

The above code returns a URL like:

```
http://example.com/files/528/Rabba_Ho_-_Falak_Shabir_Song.html.
```